# Sending straight key/value pairs in FHIR

Tags: java, hl7-fhir

I am a programmer and I am new at my company.  I am trying to populate a FHIR resource with simple key/value pairs that we use to communicate with a "sister IIS" that we also write.  All we need to do is to send two strings across.

But when I try to look through the FHIR spec on the appropriate resource to use, I am confused.

Comment: What kind of data is described in the resource?

Answer (score 1):

Parts of this should probably be a comment, but apparently I don't rank high enough to do that.

FHIR is premised on the idea of exchanging specific "collections" of information that represent real-world business objects that have state and can reasonably be manipulated as part of a single unit of work.  What you're describing doesn't seem to fit into that paradigm (though more information about the specifics of the use-case - e.g. what kinds of key/value pairs, how many are sent, how are they related - would be helpful).  In theory the Observation resource can be treated as a simple name/value pair - Observation.name  and Observation.value, but I'm not clear that's appropriate for your use-case

Comment: Yes - why? if all you're exchanging is name/value pairs, why use FHIR? If you're doing other things or other content as well, then what you are doing might change the answer to your question

Comment: Well if others +1 your answers then you soon will be able to add comments.  Okay other FHIR people, lets +1 and @Brian could you approve the answer.